# Accent marks in LyX

Tags: lyx, accents, tilde, shortcut

I recently started using LyX since it's faster than plain latex but I'm having trouble adding accent marks (´ and ~) to my words (I speak spanish). I'm used to using \' and \~ like in plain latex but I find that for LyX I have to use the symbols from my keyboard directly. Many people are comfortable with this but I find changing from an english keyboard to a spanish keyboard to be very annoying. Is there some comfortable and quick way to keep using these commands (\' and \~) or similar ones for LyX?

I know there's the option of introducing latex text in LyX and then using these commands but that'd be very annoying...

Comment: I don't know LyX, but in LaTeX, loading the `utf8` inputencoding, I simply type `é`, `á` and `ñ` on my keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid that because I want to use the english keyboard. With the spanish keyboard the placement of some symbols like \, ^, {, }, =, etc. are very confusing.

Comment: The alternatives are (a) insert ERT (evil red text) boxes  with (CTRl+L)  for text with accents  to obtain obfuscate source text in  `espa\~nol`, or   (b) do not type any  `ñ` nor accents  («manana sera otro dia») and use extensively the spanish spellchecker.  Una mala idea en ambos casos. Créeme, si escribes con frecuencia en español, usa teclados con Ñ. Sólo hay que acostumbrarse un poco. Con él podrás escribir también en inglés cómodamente , y sin la  cambiar la configuración del teclado ¡pero no al contrario!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question since I solved it months ago and didn't mention it. I started using Linux as well and found out about the Compose key. Since then I use the right alt key as compose key which allows me to type RAlt+'+(vowel) to add accents and RAlt+~+n to use ñ. I can also use RAlt+?+? to make a ¿ and RAlt+!+! to make a ¡. To use it on windows I downloaded WinCompose which works the same way.

This is the best solution I found and I became used to it. If anyone was having a similar problem I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I post my opinion in an answer. Also, I think this could be an answer.

I am also a Spanish speaker, and I use an English keyboard, but I use dead keys, so every time I type `'` my OS waits for another `'` or `<SPC>` to using as quotation mark, or a vowel to accent it. Or, I can accent vowels using `Alt Gr`, and type `ñ` also with `Alt Gr` + `n`

On Windows, if I'm not wrong, you should use US - International keyboard layout, and On GNU/Linux, US (International with dead keys).